# Cookie Authentication: How to access a returning user

Tags: asp.net-core, f#

I have studied a couple examples of ASP.Net Core 2.0 Cookie Authentication.
However, I still don't see the code that checks for a returning user via a cookie.

Please note that I'm not a web developer. As a result, I realize that my question may appear foolish.

As I understand, the browser sends the cookie to the server per client request. However, I just don't see the server logic for this in the examples that I've studied. Hence, I only see logic for logging in the user the very first time based a username and password that's explicitly passed in.

**Expectation:**

I expected the server to explicitly check if a cookie exists when requesting the index page of the website. If a cookie does exist, I would expect to see some logic to address a user that's already logged in.

- [Giraffe example](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/master/samples/SampleApp/SampleApp/Program.fs#L121)
- [Tutorial example](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/09/16/cookie-authentication-asp-net-core-2-0/)

Here's my code:

```
let loginHandler =
    fun (next : HttpFunc) (ctx : HttpContext) ->

        Tasks.Task.Run(fun _ -> StackOverflow.CachedTags.Instance() |> ignore) |> ignore

        task {
            let! data = ctx.BindJsonAsync<LogInRequest>()
            let  email = data.Email.ToLower()

            if   authenticate email data.Password
                 then match login email with
                      | Some provider -> 
                          let claims = [ Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email) ]
                          let identity = ClaimsIdentity(claims, authScheme)
                          let user     = ClaimsPrincipal(identity)

                          do!     ctx.SignInAsync(authScheme, user)
                          return! json provider next ctx

                      | None -> return! (setStatusCode 400 >=> json "Invalid login") next ctx
                 else return! (setStatusCode 400 >=> json "Invalid login") next ctx
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at the giraffe example.

The statements `services.AddAuthentication(authScheme)` and `services.AddCookie(cookieAuth)` will add various services to the services collection, making them available for injection.

The statement `app.UseAuthentication()` adds services to the [middleware pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x).  A middleware service is something that runs on every request.

The service that gets added by `UseAuthentication` is called [`AuthenticationMiddleware`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/1c30f33c925a97b105b3f9d34497218b0c9342b6/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs).  As you can see this middleware relies on an injected `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider` (provided by your call to `AddAuthentication`) which in turn (skipping a few steps here) relies on a service called [`CookieAuthenticationhandler`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/bd07f8b683ce793490d108b2310fa6112953d172/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs) (provided by your call to `AddCookie`) which actually does the work of authenticating via cookie.  When it is done it sets the logged in user onto the `HttpContext` which you can reference from your controllers if you need to.